# UnitTesting in sikuli - configuration from one place

Tags: unit-testing, sikuli

I would like to ask on UnitTesting in sikuli.

Is there any way to make settings from one place for all test ? Also there are any posibility to import one script (for example login to page) to other test ??

I have serious trouble with that. For example I make import file (config.py) with:

```
def setUp(self):
    ...some code...

def tearDown(self):
    ...some code...
```

It's really strange because I run test -> it's work,...and after that it didn't.
Do you have same experience? Or how you config your test ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there are a few questions that are being asked here.  I'll see if I can provide some insights for each.

> Is there any way to make settings from one place for all test ?

Like with all unit testing the setUp and tearDown are run before and after each and every unit test.

> import one script (for example login to page) to other test ??

Yes, you can reuse code.  See the following documentation:

http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#importing-other-sikuli-scripts-reuse-code-and-images

> I run test -> it's work,...and after that it didn't. Do you have same experience?

To paraphrase the documentation, save before you run and only hit the run button in the unit test panel.

http://sikuli.org/wiki/UnitTesting

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Because of many odds in the Sikuli IDE implementation of UnitTest (e.g. as in this case: import does not work), I recommend, to generally use the Python UnitTest module directly (just a few lines more coding, but total freedom to do what's needed)

see: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/1804